# I'm not able to write regular expression below file

Tags: linux, ksh

I'm doing wrong somewhere I think please let me know.There is some problem in regular expression.

```
#!/bin/ksh

file="11111111_111.XXXX"
# file="11111111_111.XXX"

case $file in

        /[0-9]*\_.*\.XXXX/)

                echo "Inside SFTP"
        ;;
        [0-9]{8}_\d*\.XXX)

                echo "Inside WHS"
        ;;

        *)
                echo "There is no file"

        ;;
esac
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Please formulate a complete question and give examples.

Comment: case evaluations use wildcards, not regex.

Comment: @speakr thnx 4 ur reply basically I'm trying  to match this file 11111111_111.XXXX and want to achieve through case statement.

Answer (score 0):

case-patterns are not regular expressions in bash.  They are instead expanded according to the rules for "Pathname Expansion".  Do `man bash` and search for that phrase to see the details.

Comment: sorry @Peder this is korn shell.

Comment: Your example said bash earlier.  I'm not a ksh expert, but I believe the same holds true there.  The first manpage for ksh that google turned up reinforced that belief.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

There are different versions of ksh with different syntax.  Matching is with [file name patterns](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh) which are different from regular expressions from other languages.  I have found the following pattern works on Linux and AIX:

```
+([0-9])_+([0-9]).XXXX
```

At the lowest common level, there is no support for character classes like `\d` or for number of matches `{n}`, so if you want to match exactly eight digits you will need to put in `[0-9]` eight times.

Comment: thanx 4 ur reply I got below error case.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
case.sh: line 8: `     {8}(\d)_+(\d)\.XXXX)

Comment: But I get the syntax error running on AIX.  So ksh syntax differs between Linux and AIX.